# Why is it allowed to make a non-static reference from static object?

Tags: java, android

Here is an example:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    Button button;
    public int i;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i = 10; // How can this be possible?
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that's a static object? - EDIT: Apologies if this came off snippy. I was really asking for clarification. What is it you think is static, and why do you think that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Anonymous (inner) classes (`new View.OnClickListener()` in this case) are not static, they are non-static inner classes.
- A non-static inner class has an implied relationship to the instance of the containing outer class (`Test` in this case) through which the inner class was created.  Its like the inner class has an implied ivar to that points to its related instance of the outer class.
- The inner class can access the ivars, like `i`, of its outer class through this relationship.

Answer (score 5):

That's not an static object. That's why it's possible.

Comment: if it were static , you meant it wouldn't be accessible , is it ?

Comment: @org.life.java: A static inner class can't access non-static fields of the class it's defined in because it isn't associated with a specific instance of that class. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @ColinD I know that , but it seems Cristian means that It can't access static fields

Comment: @org.life.java: I don't see anything about what he says that suggests that.

Answer (score 3):

Where is the static object? What you have there is an anonymous inner class- but you made in instance of it when you called the constructor with the new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
 i = 10; // How can this be possible?
```

`i` is class member and it can be access by class method for your code ,

what did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

There is no static object in sight here. You have an instance of an anonymous inner class (the `View.OnClickListener`), but no static objects.

EDIT: I'm wondering if perhaps you're confusing `static` variables with [local (*non*-member) `final` variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#262890). *This has nothing directly to do with static variables, but I can see how a (self-described) newbie might get them confused.*

> Any local variable, formal method
>   parameter or exception handler
>   parameter used but not declared in an
>   inner class must be declared `final`,
>   and must be definitely assigned
>   before the body of the inner class.

Modifying your example, here's a case that's **not** allowed:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        int i = 0; // This is non-final; access to it from an inner class is not allowed.
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i = 10; // Compiler error
            }
        });
    }
```

And here's another that's **not** allowed:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final int i = 0; // This is final; read-only access to it from an inner class is allowed.
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i = 10; // Compiler error -- can't modify a final variable.
            }
        });
    }
```

But this **is** allowed:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final int i = 0; // This is final; read-only access to it from an inner class is allowed.
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int j = i; // OK
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation to this: it's possible because the (anonymous) class of type `View.OnClickListener` you're creating is *not* static and hence keeps a hidden reference to its outer class. That being said:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i = 10;
        }
```

is equivalent to:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Test.this.i = 10;
        }
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that the `OnClickListener` is qualified by the `View`.  It is not actually `static`.  The following are equivalent:

```
import android.view.View;
...
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

and

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
...
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```